# Forma mais rápida de iterar sobre linhas em python, pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Estou tendo uma certa dificuldade de desempenho no código, pois está demorando muito para rodar.

Eu tenho o seguinte DataFrame. **(Exemplo pois o que estou usando é muito maior)**

```
    orders = {'Código': [600, 600, 601, 602],
              'Num. Pedido': [1000, 1000, 1002, 1003],
              'Data Pedido': ['10/01', '10/01', '08/09', 12/01],
              'Sabor': ['Calabresa', 'Mussarela', 'Pepperoni', 'Portuguesa'],
              'Quantidade': [1, 1, 1, 1],
              'Metade': [1, 2, 1, 1],
              'Meia': ['Sim', 'Sim', 'Não', 'Não']
              'Preço': [40.0, 32.0, 45.0, 35.0]} 

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=orders)
```

O que acontece é, o pedido 1000 é praticamente igual ao pedido 1000, o que muda é o Sabor a Metade e o Preço. O que eu quero fazer é colocar o Sabor de uma metade ao lado da segunda metade por exemplo, Calabresa+Mussarela. E dividir o preço por 2 porque o preço  está inteiro. Eu fiz da seguinte forma, porém está rodando a mais de 10 horas.

```
cache_metade = {}
df_final = pd.DataFrame()
lista = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    
    if index not in cache_metade:
        
        df_metade = df.loc[meioameio['Num. Pedido'] == row['Num. Pedido']]
        df_metade = df_metade.loc[df_metade['Data Pedido'] == row['Data Pedido']]
        df_metade = df_metade.loc[df_metade['Código'] == row['Código']]
        df_metade = df_metade.loc[df_metade['Metade'] != row['Metade']]
        df_metade = df_metade[~df_metade.index.isin(cache_metade)]
        
        if len(df_metade.index) > 0:
            
            metade_index = df_metade.index[0]
            metade = df_metade.iloc[0]
                
            if row['Sabores'] and metade['Sabores'] is not None:
                
                metade['Sabor'] = metade['Sabor'] + "+" + row['Sabor']
                metade['Preço'] = (metade['Preço'] / 2) + (row['Preço'] / 2)
                lista.append(row['Código'])
                df_final = df_final.append(metade)
                cache_metade[index] = True
                cache_metade[metade_index] = True

drop = df[df['Código'].isin(lista)].index
df_pedidos = df.drop(drop)
df_pedidos = pd.concat([df_pedidos, df_final])
```

Será que tem outra forma de fazer isso? Uma forma que fique mais eficiente. Lembrando, a base de dados que tenho é muito maior da que eu exemplifiquei.

Comment: É um sistema real ou é um exercício?

Comment: É um projeto que estou criando

Comment: Se é comercial não use o dataframe no atendimento, ele é melhor aproveito para a análise dos dados e a forma que os registros estão fragmentados é ineficaz. Já conhece SQLite? O python tem um módulo dedicado a esse DB. Veja [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)

Comment: E como ficaria a coluna "Metade"?

Comment: Podes colocar um pequeno df de exemplo de como seria o resultado final pf

Comment: @Miguel

orders = {'Código': [600, 601, 602],  'Num. Pedido': [1000, 1002, 1003],
          'Data Pedido': ['10/01', '08/09', '12/01'], 'Sabor': ['Calabresa+Mussrela', 'Pepperoni', 'Portuguesa'],  'Quantidade': [1, 1, 1], 'Metade': ['1+2', '2', '1', '1'],
          'Meia': ['Sim', 'Sim', 'Não', 'Não'], 'Preço': [36.0, 45.0, 35.0]}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tendo o seguinte dataframe original:

```
   Código Data Pedido Meia Metade  Num. Pedido  Preço Quantidade       Sabor
0     600       10/01  Sim      1         1000   40.0          1   Calabresa
1     600       10/01  Sim      2         1000   32.0          1   Mussarela
2     601       08/09  Não      1         1002   45.0          1   Pepperoni
3     602       12/01  Não      1         1003   35.0          1  Portuguesa
```

Logo de seguida todo esse código pode ser reduzido para:

```
df['Quantidade'] = df['Quantidade'].astype(str) # cast para str para podermos concatenar
df['Metade'] = df['Metade'].astype(str) # cast para str para podermos concatenar
df_final = df.groupby(['Código', 'Data Pedido', 'Num. Pedido', 'Meia'], as_index=False).agg({'Preço': 'mean', 'Metade': '+'.join, 'Sabor': '+'.join, 'Quantidade': '+'.join})
```

df_final:

```
   Código Data Pedido  Num. Pedido Meia Quantidade                Sabor Metade  Preço
0     600       10/01         1000  Sim        1+1  Calabresa+Mussarela    1+2   36.0
1     601       08/09         1002  Não          1            Pepperoni      1   45.0
2     602       12/01         1003  Não          1           Portuguesa      1   35.0
```

Vamos agrupar por `['Código', 'Data Pedido', 'Num. Pedido', 'Meia']` e realizar as operações pretendidas para cada uma das outras colunas na função [agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html).

Pelo que percebi é isto que queres.

Mas tal como dito em comentários se estes dados estão a vir de uma base de dados é melhor que trabalhes (faças a query) lá.